# How to create proxies with wild card paths in Azure api manager?

Tags: azure-api-management

Good Afternoon,

I have a situation where three swagger files will have different resources but they belong to the same domain. And I can't merge them into a single swagger as we have many such scenarios and managing of a single swagger and single api proxy will be a big over head.

For example:

I have 3 apis with the following paths and resources

/supermarket/v1/aisles/{aisleId}/itemcategories

/supermarket/v1/aisles/{aisleId}/itemcategories/{itemcategoryId}/seasonedvegetabletypes

/supermarket/v1/aisles/{aisleId}itemcategories/{itemcategoryId}/seasonedvegetabletypes/{vegetablestypeId}/apples

All the above 3 should be in 3 different swagger files, so I need to create 3 api proxies for the above.

Since the path suffix is same for all of them "/supermaket" the Azure API Manager will not allow to create another api proxy with the same path suffix as it MUST Be unique.

So to achieve this in Apigee Edge (Google Edge) api management product. I will have the basepaths as below

/supermarket/v1
/supermarket/v1/aisles/*/itemcategories/
/supermarket/v1/aisles/*/itemcategories/*/seasonedvegetabletypes

so that I can avoid the unique path constraint also achieve creating 3 api proxies.

But the Azure API Manager is not accepting the "wildcard" entries into the API Path Suffix field when creating the API Proxy.

Note:

You may suggest combining the 3 apis into a single swagger file might solve the issue but the example I gave above is only 30% of the swagger and we have many such paths that will fall into a single business domain so we must have them in different swagger files and different api proxies.

We should be in a position to deploy different API Proxies with the same path suffix by allowing wild cards or regex into the API Path Suffix.

Your help to resolve this is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point this is a limitation that can't be worked around. The only way to make APIM serve those URIs is to put all of them under single API, which is not what you want, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Thanks for that @Vitaliy. It is a bit of pain to change the design to match the product implementation limitations :-( but yeah agree it is what it is the moment. We have raised this with Microsoft hope they look into including this in their upcoming releases.